# Insertion Sort (Ordenação por inserção)

Tags: java, classificação

Alguém poderia me dar exemplos do cotidiano em que é utilizado o método de ordenação por inserção?

Obs.: Sem ser ordenação de cartas

Answer (score 5):

Em geral, a inserção por ordenação é usada na prática quando o conjunto de dados a ser ordenados é pequeno ou já está quase ordenado.

A inserção por ordenação demanda uma quantidade de permutações proporcional ao quadrado do número de elementos no pior caso (**O(n<sup>2</sup>)**). Os algoritmos ótimos (mergesort, heapsort, timsort, versões modernas de shellsort, etc) demandam no pior caso tempo proporcional ao número de elementos vezes o logaritmo de tal número no pior caso (**O(n log n)**).

Porém, quando não estivermos falando de uma algoritmo de ordenação que trate do pior caso, quando soubermos de antemão que os dados a serem ordenados têm poucas permutações, então a ordenação por inserção pode ser mais rápida. Uma vez que o processo de permutação é bem mais simples do que os processos para ordenação que são usados por algoritmos mais complexos (tal como o mergesort), para conjuntos de dados pequenos, a ordenação por inserção também pode ser mais rápida.

Além disso, vale mencionar o caso do timsort. O timsort é um algoritmo bem complicado de ordenação dinâmico que aproveita-se de ordenações parciais nos dados. Ele combina o mergesort com a ordenação por inserção. Quando o timsort detecta que alguma subparte a ser ordenada está quase ordenada ou tem um tamanho suficientemente pequeno, ele usará a ordenação por inserção nessa parte, enquanto que usará o mergesort em partes que forem maiores ou estiverem bem desordenadas.